# Update environment variable in Postman

Tags: api, testing, postman, newman

I'm using Newman and Postman to test a website.

My Newman command construction looks like:

```
newman run
"https://api.getpostman.com/collections/{collection_id}?apikey={my_postman_api_key}"
--environment "https://api.getpostman.com/environments/{environment_id}?apikey={my_postman_api_key}"
--export-environment "https://api.getpostman.com/environments/{environment_id}?apikey={my_postman_api_key}"
--insecure
```

This all works fine but my environment values don't update after the Newman run.

In my request, I use a `Pre-request Script` to update the value:

```
var mail = pm.environment.get("mail_randomizer");
pm.environment.set("mail_randomizer", Number(mail) + 1);
```

After sending this request in Postman, the value for the `mail_randomizer` variable has gone up by 1 but after running the request using Newman, it doesn't work.

How can I export the environment correctly in Newman?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What happens? Can you provide any images of what you're seeing? The Newman environment export command looks right to me.

Comment: The variable in the environment doesn't update

Comment: Yeah I get that...What happens to the query? Did it run with the updated value but not export the new value? Does any of the tests that you may have fail? Need more details to know what's going on.

Comment: Next query will not work because my value should be unique. So, I receive a red failed assertion in Newman log. But if I will re-send this request in Postman, my variable will be successfully updated and will be available to the Newman test. The first test will be passed because my value will be still unique, but after that, the next Newman test will fail because my value will not update in the environment.

Comment: @EugeneTruuts Can you share the collection in which this is happening? Retract any sensitive information. (Replace url's with postman-echo.com if you need)

Comment: To share the collection: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/collections/sharing_collections

Answer (score 0):

create

.env : environment variable let's say

url = http://localhost:3000/api

.env.example should be

url =

in your test call :

var local-url = process.env.url;

add in your package json

npm install dotenv

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54258709/edit) your post and fix the formatting. Code or shell commands for any OS should be either indented with four spaces, or pre- and postfixed with three backticks (`\``)